# Hibernate OneToMany creating many records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this two object Input and IndisponibleSegment with a relation one to many respectively:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name= "input")   
    public class Input {

    private long _id;   
    private String _name;
    private Set<IndisponibleSegment> _indisponibleSegments;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getName() {
      return _name;
    }

    public void setName(String inName) {
      this._name = inName;
    }


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public long getId() {
    return _id;
  }
  public void setId(long inId) {
    this._id = inId;
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "input", cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public Set<IndisponibleSegment> getIndisponibleSegments() {
    return _indisponibleSegments;
  }

  public void setIndisponibleSegments(Set<IndisponibleSegment> inIndisponibleSegments) {
    this._indisponibleSegments = inIndisponibleSegments;
  }

}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "indisponible_segment")
public class IndisponibleSegment {

private Lane _lane;
private int _id;
private Input _input;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value={org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="input_id")
public Input getInput() {
  return _input;
}

public void setInput(Input inInput) {
  this._input = inInput;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
  return _id;
}

public void setId(int inId) {
  this._id = inId;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "lane", nullable = false)
public Lane getLane() {
  return _lane;
}

public void setLane(Lane inLane) {
  this._lane = inLane;
}

}
```

My problem is that everytime run a code like:

```
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    Input input = dao.get(Input.class, new Long(1));
    if(input==null) {
      input = new Input();
      input.setName("Input 1");
    }

    Set<IndisponibleSegment> islist = new HashSet<>();
    IndisponibleSegment is = new IndisponibleSegment();
    is.setInput(input);

    is.setLane(Lane.LANE_FAST);
    islist.add(is);

    input.setIndisponibleSegments(islist);

    dao.saveOrUpdate(input);
```

I get a new entry in the indisponible_segments table and the old is not removed, thus still there.

I have tried all combinations I can think of: Cascade, delete-orphans, unique constranits... all. What am I doing wrong? All I want is that if I set a new the indisponibleSegments the old ones are deleted.

Comment: When you do "dao.saveOrUpdate(input);", do you see any "delete" query on console?

Comment: No delete. Just one update for the 'inputs' and one insert each time for the 'indisponible_segment'

Comment: By using 'merge' instead all my problems are gone... Not so sure why, I guess because I am closing always the session on every transaction it is better to use merge instead.